# Where are values stored in memory in dart?

Tags: dart, memory, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

I know that in Dart all data types are Objects, including numbers and booleans, in other languages numbers and booleans are stored on the stack and complex data like objects or lists are stored on the heap, in Dart how does it store this? values in memory? I would like to know just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on optimizations, but mostly values are allocated on a garbage collected heap.

The Dart language specification does not say how to represent values in memory, so it's up to the individual implementation.

On the web, values are stored as JavaScript values, in whatever way the JavaScript engine stores those. That's usually a garbage collected heap, plus whatever optimizations the JS JIT can do.

Natively, the VM allocates a garbage collected heap and stores objects in that.
The heap has different regions for different types and sizes of objects,
with specific regions for newly allocated objects, and only moves them to old-space if they survive long enough (q.v. generational garbage collection).

Constant values are allocated in heap segments that may even be shared between isolates.
Small integers (for fairly large sizes of "small" on 64-bit platforms) are not even allocated, they are stored directly inside the "object reference" (tagged pointer), using a tagging bit for separating them from memory references (called "Smi"s, for "small integers").

The VM *can* optimize some values to stay on the stack (stack allocation for simple, short-lived values, allocation sinking composite values into groups of simple values). Whether it is safe depends on the usage and structure of the object.

Some values may never be materialized in memory at all. If the compiler can see that it's only used shortly after, it can stay in a register

Simple values, like integers, doubles and booleans, may also be unboxed and never have an actual object allocated. Doing `a + b + c` where all are integers, there is no reason to allocate an object to store the `a + b` intermediate result, it can just stay as a machine integer until the value of `c` has been found and added to it. Intermediate results (which a recognizable as such) can be stored in any way, since nobody else than the compilers own code can access them.

An unboxed boolean value may never be anything more than a status register flag. Doing `if (a < b) ... else ...`, where `a` and `b` are integers, can end up with just the (intel syntax) machine instructions `cmp rcx, rdx; jge elseLable;`.

There is currently no way to *control* representation.
You cannot ask to have an object allocated on the stack.
You might be able to get it, if you ensure that the allocating function and the object itself never leaks any references to it, and the function is hot enough that it gets optimized by expensive optimizations. And the stars are right.

Optimizations are valid only as long as they are not observable. When any code actually looks at a value, it must behave as the language requires, which for most objects includes having a single unique identity when queried using `identical`. (Record objects in Dart 3 will not be required to have a persistent identity. Numbers are *defined* to have the same identity if they have the same value, so they can be safely unboxed and reboxed, it just may cost extra when doing `identical` on them.)

So, it depends (on optimizations).